# git/repo error , when i used the command "repo upload .",there is an error :

Tags: git

when i used the command "repo upload .",there is an error :

MSM8926_LA20_VoLTE_KitKat/LINUX/android/SBM/ test2
       (https://secure.sharp.co.jp/android_review/gerrit/ssh_info: Cannot parse response)

thank you very much!

Comment: I've never heard of a "repo upload" command in Git.  Are you trying to push to a remote?

Comment: @Makoto it is used with git-repo from google: https://code.google.com/p/git-repo/

Comment: Okay.  So, could you describe the exact steps you're taking that cause you to get this error?

Comment: Problem solved. This error happeded because the remote server was not ready. My company uses repo/git and gerrit to manager source cdoes.you could try knowing about then if intersted.thanks!